# Pc stuck at boot time after canceling 19.04 installation

Tags: 19.04

i got a problen with my pc i started installing ubuntu 19.04 and i accidently closed the terminal where the update was running which cancelled the installation . I rebootes my computer since then but it is stuck at boot time , here is what is displayed : 
(I wish i could post an image but i cant ...)
A lot of [OK] messages 
The last lines are :

```
[Ok] Started Login Service 
[Ok] Started Raise network interfaces
[Ok] Started Save/Restore Sound Card State
```

Comment: Anybody Here Please ?

Comment: Look up how to get into the recovery console. Use the recovery console to backup your data. Then complete the upgrade. If the upgrade fails, then clean-install 18.94 and restore your data from the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I booted my pc in recovery mode with the old kernel version then I ran dpkg repair broken packages and it worked !